# Suitable Azure replacement for Auth0

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization, auth0, azure-authentication

I have an ASP .Net Core 2.2 Web API hosted as an Azure App Service. Then there is an Angular SPA which consumes this API, hosted on Azure Storage as a static website.

I am currently using Auth0 as our authentication and identity server. I am looking at replacing Auth0 with Azure, but I've spent a couple of days now trying to figure out what I should be doing and I am completely lost.

So, the purpose that Auth0 is currently serving, and which I would like Azure to serve instead, is to protect my Web API, as well as give it identity services so that the API knows which user is logged in. So when the front end makes a call to the API, Auth0 automatically redirects it to a login page. Here the user can log in using an existing account (including social accounts) or she can create a new account. Once logged in, Auth0 provides the front end with an access token. The front end then includes this access token in the header of every API call. The access token includes identity information which the API uses to know which user is making the call. All users are stored in Auth0. So when a new user uses the front end web app, Auth0 redirects them to the login screen, where they select "Sign Up", and create an account in Auth0. Any user can do this btw - it is a public web app which anyone can sign up and use.

So, when looking at using Azure instead of Auth0, what first confuses me is that there are various authentication services:

1. In the Azure portal, under my app service, under "Authentication / Authorization", there is a toggle switch labelled "App Service Authentication". If I turn this on, I can set up Authentication Providers.
2. In the Azure portal, there is Azure Active Directory, which I guess ties in with the above?
3. There is also Azure B2C.

What is the difference between Azure App Service Authentication and Azure B2C? Which one should I be using? What is the difference between points 1 and 2 above? Some examples I've seen use point 1 and some use point 2.

Sorry if this is a very vague question. I am just struggling to figure out in which direction to head. I found Auth0 quite simple, but unfortunately I cannot say the same about Azure authentication. I basically just want to figure out which Azure option would be best suited to replace Auth0 as I am using it now. Thanks

Comment: What problems are you running into with Auth0?

Comment: Hi Dan. No problems with Auth0. I just thought it would be nice to host everything on Azure. I've already got the backend API and front-end SPA on Azure, and I'm using Azure Blob Storage for the document storage. So i thought if I move authentication to Azure too, then everything could be together on Azure. Thought that could be convenient...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure B2C is the proper option to replace user authentication, however you would have to go with OWIN or another solution to actually provide application specific identity/authorization pipeline. 
For public-facing site I would not go with straight up azure AD for customer logins, that’s targeted more towards enterprise customer with identities in federated, office365 or on prem Active Directory.

To be honest I’m surprised you’re planning on moving from auth0 to AAD. I’m thinking about doing the opposite.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dmitri. The only reason I considered switching from Auth0 to AAD was because I'm already hosting the API as an app service on Azure, the front end is also on Azure Storage as a static web site, plus I recently moved the document storage from Amazon S3 to Azure Blob Storage. So I thought the only missing piece now was to use Azure for authentication too. Then the entire solution would be residing nicely in one location/one provider... No other reason... :)

Comment: I've compared the B2C option with Auth0 last year and Auth0 seemed a more robust choice with better support and documentation. I know Azure team iterates very fast, so it's possible that they now have additional capabilities in B2C that bring it closer to Auth0 level.

Answer (score 2):

I think the "replacement" would be using Identity Server, but there's no PaaS version for it on Azure. So you should go with Azure AD or Azure AD B2C.

If you want just to create users and groups you should use Azure AD. But if you have plans to enable 3rd party identities to access your app (such as Facebook, Google or Linkedin), then you should use Azure AD B2C. For more info, please read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview